# Menu populated with database on php

Tags: php

so I am building a menu to a site, ant the menu will be populated by the database, when I query the database I get something like this array:

Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [nome] => Home
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [nome] => Tutorials
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [nome] => Photoshop
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [nome] => Illustrato
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [nome] => Web Design
            [parent_id] => 2
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [nome] => HTML
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [nome] => CSS
            [parent_id] => 5
        )

)
```

I would like to search it and get just the child items, for instance:

```
function getChild($needle){
    ...
    return $array
}
```

where $array, is the information of the children:

```
print_r(getChild(2));
```

would output something like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 4 [2] => 5 )
```

in this example it returns the ids but it could return  an array with the complete info for each one of the items...

I could query the database again and obtain the same results but I'm afraid that it is not a good practice. For example if I have a gigantic menu, the script would be querying too much the database and that would slow down the rendering of the page too much.

I am tiered of searching a way of doing this I'm already dizzy and exhausted...

I realize that in this example I have no links but it is easy to add them in the end, that's why I don't work with them for now :P

Answer (score 1):

It might look something like this (assuming I understand your issue properly):

```
function getChild( $needle, $sourceArray )
{ 
    $ret = array();
    for( $i = $needle; $i < $sourceArray.count(); $i++ )
    { 
         array_push( $ret, $sourceArray[ $i ][ 'id ' ]) ;
    }

    return $ret;
}
```

**EDITED:** the function isn't *length()* - it's *count()*

Comment: I tryed your sugestion but it guives a fatal error **
Fatal error:  Call to undefined function length() in ...**

Comment: That solution is ridiculous and certainly doesn't do what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to pass your array into the function getChild():

```
getChild($data, 1, 2)
```

Something like this:

```
function getChild(){
    $results = [];
    $args = func_get_args();
    $arrays = array_shift($args);

    foreach ($arrays as $subarr) {
        $curr_results = [];
        $keys = array_keys($subarr);

        foreach ($args as $index) {
            $curr_results[] = $subarr[$keys[$index]];
        }
        $results[] = $curr_results;
    }

    return $results;
}




$data = [

["id" => 1, "nome" => "Home", "parent id" => 0],
["id" => 2, "nome" => "Tutorials", "parent id" => 0],
["id" => 3, "nome" => "Photoshop", "parent id" => 0],
["id" => 4, "nome" => "Illustrato", "parent id" => 2],

];

print_r(getChild($data, 1, 2));

--output:--

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Home
            [1] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tutorials
            [1] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Photoshop
            [1] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Illustrato
            [1] => 2
        )

)
```

I have to say, that seems like a stupid way to obfuscate your code.  It would be much clearer to write:

```
getChildData($data, "nome", "parent_id");
```

Instead, you are trying to access an associative array with numeric indexes.

Comment: See i don't want to obfuscate anything, the function getChild is in fact my problem, I don't exactly know how to write it, thats why I asked for help...

Comment: Did my answer provide the solution you were looking for?

Comment: neither questions were what I needed, but each one of them helped in some way or another to reach the result I needed... now I don't know exactly what to do...

Comment: How does my solution fail to do what you asked: "in this example it returns the ids but it could return an array with the complete info for each one of the items..."  You asked for a function that takes an undetermined number of integers as arguments, and returns the values at those positions in each sub array.  What did you actually want?

Comment: I already solved the problem with the help of the both answers and a piece of information from other site, I wanted to filter the initial array(that is what I get when I query the db with pdo, thats why I said:"I could query the database again and obtain the same results but I'm afraid that it is not a good practice.") 

After resting for a bit I searched again and found a way to do exactly what I wanted in other website, I adapted it to what I already had...

Comment: So you are going to hide your solution from people who may have the same problem as you?

Comment: no not at all, I am working on an answer, but I have a lot of things to do, so for now it will have to wait... and for your info I don't like your attitude, your competitive aggressiveness or something, sorry... Still I'm glad that you tried to help me... I don't want to seam ungrateful, I'm just being sincere...